# How to combine two CompletableFuture lists of custom objects and return a flux object?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am new to Reactive Java and I got two api requests that return two CompletableFuture containing two lists of custom objects A. I need to somehow combine these, serialize the objects, create a new list of another custom object B that one field has the serialized A-objects, and return it as one Flux object. I have been trying s:mething like this but it doesn't work.

```
CompletableFuture<List<ResponseModels.A>> list1 = api.getListOfObjects();
CompletableFuture<List<ResponseModels.A>> list2 = api.getListOfOtherObjects();

CompletableFuture<ResponseModels.B> l = list1.thenApply(list1Objects -> list2.thenApply(list2Objects -> {
                        List<String> list1OfStrings = fop.stream().map(otcPaymentResultDTO -> JsonUtils.gsonFullBody.toJson(ResponseModels.B.builder()                                .payload(JsonUtils.gsonFullBody.toJson(list1Objects))
                                )).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        List<String> list2OfStrings = dvp.stream().map(otcDvPDTO -> JsonUtils.gsonFullBody.toJson(ResponseModels.B.builder()
                                .payload(JsonUtils.gsonFullBody.toJson(list2Objects)))).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        List<String> combinedList = Stream.concat(list1OfStrings.stream(), list2OfStrings.stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return combinedList;
                    })));
return Flux.just(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mono.fromFuture` to convert from `CompletableFuture` to `Mono`.
Below code will return `Flux<ResponseModels.B>`:

```java
Flux<ResponseModels.A> aFlux = Mono.fromFuture(() -> api.getListOfObjects())
                                   .flatMapIterable(x -> x);
Flux<ResponseModels.A> bFlux = Mono.fromFuture(() -> api.getListOfOtherObjects())
                                   .flatMapIterable(x -> x);


return Flux.merge(aFlux, bFlux)
           .map(aModel -> /* json transformation logic here */);
```